# Does changing the picture folder path of older website affect SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, url, images, cdn

I have a 2 years old WordPress based picture website. Now I am planning to use CDN for my website. But the problem is I have to move my picture folder to a subdomain.

For instance my current path is `example.com/pics/yyy.jpg` and have to change it to `cdn.example.com/pics/yyy.jpg`.

Since the pictures play vital role in my site's SEO I am afraid to change the folder path, but at the same time I am getting more number of hits eventually. Should I compromise my site speed for SEO or the impact would be less if I try CDN?

Answer (score 2):

If you do a proper redirect from the old to the new location (.htaccess or a similar technique), after about a month or so everything should be back to normal. During this month you may experience some SE rankings "dance", but if it will really impact performance (e.g. decrease page loading speed), I think you should definitely go forward with the change, since search engines love fast loading pages - be it by using a CDN or a powerful server.